# pandas - count overal elements after converting one column to a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file and read into pandas DataFrame using
    `df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')`

My data looks like the following:

```
choice    userid
A\nB\nC    111111
A\nC      222222
B         333333
```

From this DataFrame, I would like to achieve my goals by two steps:

(1) split the values in the **choice** column by '\n'

(2) count how many As, Bs and Cs in my CSV file.

I've tried:
    `target = df['choice'].str.split('\n')`
    `target.value_counts()`

But got the error as:
    `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Could anyone tell me how I can achieve my goal. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There seems some kind of inconsistency with the `\n` in the data. Some rows contain all newline characters while contain just \. In any case, try `df.choice.str.split(r"[n\\]+").apply(len).sum()` if your data looks exactly like what's presented here.

Comment: I had some difficulty in formatting my data in the blockquote way. It looks better than my original submission.

Comment: @TongLiu try this `df.choice.str.split(r"[n\\]+").apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()`.

Comment: @Evert I copied and pasted a wrong line just now, and fixed it with the exact error I had.

Comment: @Abdou Your new code works! It gets me the same results as what I got using dictionary structure to record my count by reading CSV line by line. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: @TongLiu, feel free to mark the question answered when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following should do:

```
df.choice.str.split(r"[\\n]+", expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

or

```
df.choice.str.split(r"[\\n]+").apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
```

Both should return:

```
C    2
A    2
B    2
dtype: int64
```